# something wrong in presenting highcharts using django

Tags: django, highcharts

I was stuck in passing dict's data to highchart using django

here's my views.py code. My thought is trying to pass the database's data to dictionary `data` , then pass its to `user_chart.html's highchairs`

```
def user_chart(request):

    user_data = User_Data.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)
    data = {'words':[], 'click_times':[]}
    for i in user_data:
        data['words'].append(i.word)
        data['click_times'].append(i.click_times)

    xAxis = {"title": {"text": 'ss'}, 'categories': data['words']}
    yAxis = {"title": {'text': 'fdfd'}}
    series = [
        {"name": 'dfdf', "data": data['click_times']}
    ]
    content = {'xAxis': xAxis, 'yAxis': yAxis, 'series': series}
    return render(request, 'yigu/user_chart.html', content)
```

user_chart.html's code. I want to achieve a goal that highchart receives the data then present its as chart.

```
{% extends 'yigu/base_charts.html' %}

{% block body_block %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div id="chart1" style="width:450px">
          &nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  var xAxis = {{ xAxis|safe }}
  var yAxis = {{ yAxis|safe }}
  var series = {{ series|safe }}
</script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#chart1").highcharts({
            chart: {
          type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
          text: '搜索频率'
      },
      xAxis: xAxis,
      yAxis: yAxis,
      series: series
  });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

But i just got the blank response, the chart didn't show up. Anyone could give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

After reading http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/rprasad/2011/08/30/highcharts-django-admin/ I noticed  `categories: [ '{{ categories|join:"','" }}']` And i thought that maybe i should try this type. Then i change my template into something like below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#chart1").highcharts({
            chart: {
          type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
          text: '搜索频率'
      },
      xAxis: {
          title:{
            text: '词条',
          },
          categories: [ '{{ data.words|join:"','"}}']
      },
      yAxis: {
          title:{
            text: '次数'
          }
      },
      series:[{
          name:'搜索次数',
          data:[{{ data.click_times|join:"," }}]
      }]
  });
});
</script>
```

Then everything went right. I was so surprised. I hope the solution would help someone.